What is wrong with this macro expansion?
I am trying to use Dog Hoyte's Let over Lambda, Chapter 3, named let with some touch from EmacsLisp (named-let from subr-x.el).
Neither his original, nor mine slightly modified version macroexpand in SBCL. I am not sure I understand what is wrong there, can someone give me a pointer please?
(defmacro nlet (name bindings &rest body)
  "Looping construct taken from Scheme.
Like `let', bind variables in BINDINGS and then evaluate BODY,
but with the twist that BODY can evaluate itself recursively by
calling NAME, where the arguments passed to NAME are used
as the new values of the bound variables in the recursive invocation.

Implementation after D. Hoyte from \"Let over lambda\"."
  (let ((fargs (mapcar (lambda (b) (if (consp b) (car b) b)) bindings))
        (aargs (mapcar (lambda (b) (if (consp b) (cadr b))) bindings)))
    `(labels ((,name ,fargs ,@body))
       (,name ,aargs))))

When trying to macroexpand-all, it bangs with error.
Expected expansion:
(macroexpand-all
     '(nlet fact ((n n))
            (if (zerop n)
                1
              (* n (fact (- n 1))))))

=> (labels ((fact (n) (if (zerop n) 1 (* n (fact (- n 1)))))) (fact (n)))

What I get:
Illegal function call in method body:
  ((N N))
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request.
 1: [ABORT] Return to sly-db level 1.
 2: [RETRY] Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request.
 3: [*ABORT] Return to SLY's top level.
 4: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD tid=15104 "sly-channel-1-mrepl-remote-1" RUNNING {1100BC0003}>)

Backtrace:
 0: (SB-WALKER::GET-WALKER-TEMPLATE (N N) ((N N)))
 1: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-WALKER::WALK-FORM-INTERNAL))

SBCL code walker does not like my template. Why? :) Seems like it tries to execute the bindings to the label-expression during the macro expansion for some reason?

What's macroexpand-all? Standard macroexpand expands it correctly in SBCL.

You need to use unquote-splicing on the initial values, not unquote, so it becomes (fact n) instead of (fact (n))

(,name ,aargs) should be (,name ,@aargs)

I found a macroexpand-all in the sb-cltl2 package, but it doesn't give that error. What version of macroexpand-all are you using?

The one from sb-cltl2.

@Barmar Thank you for catching it! That was the one.  Now when I look at it, looks obvious, but I was blind yesterday.

When testing a new macro that has not yet worked, use macroexpand-1.  You need to expand just that macro, and then stop expanding, so you can see and validate what that macro alone is doing.  If your macro generates bad output that causes other macroexpansion to choke, then macroexpand-all won't necessarily work, and even macroexpand could run into a problem, if your macro generates a bad macro call.

Yeah, that is a good advice @Kaz. I actually did macroexpand-1 and macroexpand before I posted, which worked. I was just stupid and blind and looked at bad spot. I don't know why, some sort of brainfreeze kicked in I guess .
